# CTRL-P very slow when files are not found

Tags: plugin-ctrlp

Sometimes I mis-spell the name of a file. So let's say I have a file called `ThisIsAFileName` and I start typing `ThisS...` The moment I misspell the filename (and there are no hits whatsoever), CTRL-P becomes incredibly slow. It displays each next letter at a speed of about 1 character every 5 seconds. So if I accidentally type 6 extra characters I am waiting half a minute for CTRL-P to finish displaying these characters before I can undo this.

Is this something that happens regularly? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm facing same issue...

Comment: I'm still stuck in the same situation. I _try_ not to mis-spell, which is my current "fix", but if there's a better fix out there, I'm all ears.

Comment: I found [this article](https://dougblack.io/words/a-good-vimrc.html) by Doug very useful. It has a [section](https://dougblack.io/words/a-good-vimrc.html#ctrlp-section) on CtrlP. Quoting from the article > However, we can tell CtrlP to run an external command to find matching
> files. Now that we have ag installed, we can use it with CtrlP to make
> CtrlP wicked fast. Although I haven't tried using ag myself, it seems to be something worth trying.

Comment: Ctrl P is old, let try `fzf`, the performance is significantly faster.

Comment: I'm using it with ag on windows (which is considerable slower than Linux on file discovery and listing) with good results. It's not immediate, but good enough for seamlessly finding files.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable caching, if it is not enabled already:

```
let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 1
```

It significantly reduces lag and is ideal if there aren't a lot of changes inside the directory, ie not a lot of new or deleted files.  However, as files are added or removed or renamed, the file index will become stale, and it needs to be refreshed (ie re-indexed) by pressing `ctrl+p` and then `F5` (or alternatively, enter `:CtrlPClearCache` in command mode).

I prefer to use faster file search external app, and not have to deal with caching at all.  I recommend either [Ag (The Silver Searcher)](https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) or [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep). They are significantly faster than the ctrl-p's built-in search engine, and switching the engine is very easy.

Ag or Ripgrep needs to be installed first.  And then in `.vimrc`, I add the following.

If using ripgrep:

```
if executable('rg')
    let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'rg %s --files --color=never --glob ""'
    let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0
endif
```

If using ag:

```
if executable('ag')
  let g:ctrlp_user_command = 'ag -l --nocolor -g "" %s'
  let g:ctrlp_use_caching = 0
endif
```

- On Windows, Ag seems to be slower and I recommend Ripgrep instead of Ag.